# Nvidia problems with optirun when running WarCraft

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

**Problem:**
I have Nvidia problems I don't know what happen because when I run WarCraft with optirun it display errors then if I type `optirun glxgears`, it displays the same errors as when im running warcraft ..

```
optirun glxgears
[   25.424416] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[   25.424460] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

How to fix this?

**PC specs:**
`Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M`

I used `lspci | grep VGA` which gave me:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller(rev 09)
```

It seems my laptop does not detect my Nvidia GeForce GT 630M anymore. It worked before I knew that my optirun is broken, I didn't do anything.

I just installed Geany recently and make a virtual host and oh yes, i use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>sys req</kbd> + <kbd>REIUSB</kbd> because I had my laptop freeze few hours ago

Please if anyone can help i will really appreciate it.

**Solution**
I have already posted [my solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/235934/63792) as an answer below.

**Note:** I already had Bumblebee installed. It worked before, but all of a sudden my laptop suddenly doesn't recognize my VGA..

---

**New questions**

1. Why did my initial problem arise? Is it because I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>sys req</kbd> + <kbd>REIUSB</kbd> ?? Yes i typed it REIUSB and not REISUB..
2. Why did my solution work?

I already searched in google and didnt find any good/clear answer(the answers too hard for newbie to understand) please answer with details because im a newbie in ubuntu and also in computer .. i just installed ubuntu 2 weeks ago so i can learn about computer.

Comment: It think you are using a Optimus compatible VGA (A computer with an Intel and a NVidia VGA Card) Optimus switchs between that two VGAs when you play games and programs with high need of Graphical process . Bumblebee is a free and Open-source implementation of Optimus technology , It think you should download and install it .

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

what i have done :
i frustrated, i boot ubuntu live cd and try ubuntu, use 
    lspci | grep VGA

it detected my 2 vga:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0de9 (rev a1)
```

i slept, then i woke up in the morning, hope for magic happens, AND YES IT DOES, use optirun and it works! it also detected my VGA with lspci | grep VGA

note: **i already had bumblebee installed and it worked before my laptop suddenly didnt recognize my vga..**